# Bitbucket pipeline to push code to another repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

I have 2 repositories in the bitback, Repositories A and B.
I need that when someone makes a commit in repository A, the pipeline starts, and copies my code to repository B.
Now such a pipeline is used. But I get an error.

```
error: src refspec devops-test does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to
```

pipeline

```
 - date > test.txt  
 - git remote add two https://login:passwd@repo.git
 - git add .
 - git commit -m "push [scip ci]"
 - git push two devops-test --force
```

Comment: From the [`devops` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devops): "*Non-programming related questions should be asked on the DevOps Stack Exchange site.*" --- The question might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
clone:
  depth: full 
pipelines:
  branches:
    uat:
      - step:
          script: 

            - echo "sonar reports"
            - apt install -y git
            - git remote add new https://priya400:yxv7WQjgDJRZZaJNBndC@bitbucket.org/bbc-test4/firstrepo.git
            - touch test111.txt
            - git add .
            - git commit -m "push to remote"
            - git push new aws/client:devops-test --force```
````